# NGINX CORS Issues

Tags: ajax, nginx, cors

There is a server with NGINX 1.16, which is used to upload files through AJAX

Here are the configuration settings of the NGINX file

```
location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
# With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
# With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
#fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
if ($request_method = "OPTIONS") {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'http://myserver.com';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials false;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'DELETE,GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,X-Token-Auth,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;

    return 204;
}

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'http://myserver.com';
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'DELETE,GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT';
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,X-Token-Auth,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
}
```

Here are the test results for CURL

[image]

When you try to upload a file, a CORS error is displayed in the console

[image]

Maybe someone came across a similar behavior when СORS is turned on on the server, but an error pops up anyway?

UPD: It has also been noticed that headers are not displayed in the browser. There is an assumption that this is the reason, but then how to “force” the server to give headers?

[image]

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Code does not issue, written in red "(failed)"

Comment: Try disabling all your extensions, and/or try in an Incognito window. And try clearing the cookies and your browser cache for the site. And disable any anti-virus software you have installed. And try from a different browser, and from a different machine, and from a different network. The point being to eliminate the possibility that some other software running or your machine might be interfering with the request, and eliminate the possibility that some firewall setting is interfering with it, etc.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, We have already done this more than once - the results are zero. The most interesting thing is that the server does not give headers to the browser

Answer (score -1):

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'http://myserver.com'; is wrong in your setting.

```
   location / {
         if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
         }
         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
         }
         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
         }
    }
```

Comment: We tried this configuration option, this did not solve the problem

Comment: did you add header in php controller side which api you are trying to use ?

Comment: <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?> try this on server side . this is working setting . it should work bud

Comment: Perhaps this will be the last option that we will use. The problem must be tried to solve, and not to get around it))

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/291/how-to-solve-the-client-side-access-control-allow-origin-request-error-with-your-own-symfony-3-api may be this would help you.